# Ansible как задать переменные конфигурации (ansible.cfg) для групп?

Tags: ansible, devops

Проект разбит на 3 большые группы

Группа-1 - подлючение по паролю

Группа-2 - подлючение по ключу, Группа-3 - подлючение по ключу

В ansible.cfg авторизация по умолчанию - пароль. Как изменить поведение в зависимости от группы?

Что пробовал:

- удалил настройки **ansible.cfg** для *ask_pass*
- добавлял ask_pass в group_vars/[all:vars], в inventory/[group_name:vars]
- добавлял в сам плейбук

Конфиг:

```
ansible --version
ansible 2.6.0
  config file = Ansible/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = [ u'/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible
  executable location = /usr/bin/ansible
  python version = 2.7.15 (default, May 16 2018, 17:50:09) [GCC 8.1.1 20180502 (Red Hat 8.1.1-1)]

ls -gG ansible.cfg group_vars/
-rw-r--r--. 1 3257 Jul 26 20:17 ansible.cfg
group_vars/:
total 56
-rw-rw-r--. 1  847 Jan 26 20:02 DE.yml
-rw-rw-r--. 1  681 Nov 30  2017 DK.yml
-rw-rw-r--. 1 1048 Jan 26 20:02 ES.yml
-rw-rw-r--. 1 1422 Jan 30 16:53 FI.yml
-rw-rw-r--. 1 2145 Nov 15  2017 IE.yml
-rw-rw-r--. 1  877 Feb  2 15:53 LT.yml
-rw-rw-r--. 1  874 Feb  2 11:12 LV.yml
-rw-rw-r--. 1  467 Jan 29 08:39 NL.yml
-rw-rw-r--. 1 1939 Jan 26 20:02 NO.yml
-rw-rw-r--. 1 1334 Jan 29 08:39 SE.yml
lrwxrwxrwx. 1    6 Feb  3 00:34 _signoff_de.yml -> DE.yml
lrwxrwxrwx. 1    6 Feb  3 00:34 _signoff_dk.yml -> DK.yml
lrwxrwxrwx. 1    6 Feb  3 00:34 _signoff_es.yml -> ES.yml
lrwxrwxrwx. 1    6 Feb  3 00:34 _signoff_fi.yml -> FI.yml
lrwxrwxrwx. 1    6 Feb  3 00:34 _signoff_ie.yml -> IE.yml
lrwxrwxrwx. 1    6 Feb  3 00:34 _signoff_lt.yml -> LT.yml
lrwxrwxrwx. 1    6 Feb  3 00:34 _signoff_lv.yml -> LV.yml
lrwxrwxrwx. 1    6 Feb  3 00:34 _signoff_nl.yml -> NL.yml
lrwxrwxrwx. 1    6 Feb  3 00:34 _signoff_no.yml -> NO.yml
lrwxrwxrwx. 1    6 Feb  3 00:34 _signoff_se.yml -> SE.yml
lrwxrwxrwx. 1    8 Feb  3 00:34 _signoff_test.yml -> TEST.yml
lrwxrwxrwx. 1   10 Feb  3 00:34 _signoff_uk_dcm.yml -> UK_DCM.yml
lrwxrwxrwx. 1   12 Feb  3 00:34 _signoff_uk_odeon.yml -> UK_ODEON.yml
lrwxrwxrwx. 1    9 Feb  3 00:34 _signoff_uk_pd.yml -> UK_PD.yml
lrwxrwxrwx. 1   10 Feb  3 00:34 _signoff_uk_vue.yml -> UK_DCM.yml
-rw-rw-r--. 1 2145 Jan 29 08:39 TEST.yml
-rw-rw-r--. 1 2154 Feb  2 15:00 UK_DCM.yml
-rw-rw-r--. 1 2202 Jan 29 08:39 UK_ODEON.yml
-rw-rw-r--. 1 2034 Jan 30 15:18 UK_PD.yml
lrwxrwxrwx. 1   10 Feb  3 00:34 UK-VUE.yml -> UK_DCM.yml
```

Comment: А симлинки в `group_vars` не канают? У меня так.

Comment: @donRumata Благородный дон Арканарский, да есть линки, пробовал добавлять параметры в плейбуки, но походу Ansible "игнорит" их и все равно использует ansible.cfg из локали.

Comment: А если выкинуть из `ansible.cfg` авторизацию по дефолту? Всё равно ведь есть `*_vars` где всё уже прохаркоренно. И кстати. Чё за управляющий сервак и какой на нём ансибл? У меня мулька с симлинками работает на ubuntu 16.04 + официальный ppa с этим самым ансиблом.

Comment: @donRumata обновил, рабочие станции в нашем отделе это Supermicro cpu-i7/16G-RAM/ssd/ и есть еще боевой  провизионный сервер, там уже все по серьезному но крутится в VMWare на Ubunty 16.04/

Comment: Я имел ввиду "на какой ОС крутится бинарник ансибла".

Comment: Эммм... а зачем `ask_pass`? У меня без него всё ок пашет вроде бы.

Comment: @donRumata есть группа где логично только по паролю.

Comment: У меня тестовые машины линукса и боевые винды - по паролю. И все - без `аскпасса`.

Comment: @donRumata в итоге разбил проект на 3 "подгрупп" в каждую из которых включил свой ansible.cfg  но все под одинм git.

Comment: Ну тогда оформи ответ с выхлопом `tree`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как писал в комментариях, разбил проект на логические группы со своими конфигурационными файлами, добавил группу по умолчанию из которой линкуются роли в остальные.
Весь проект сидит под одним  git.

```
./
├── aws
│   ├── cache
│   ├── group_vars
│   ├── host_vars
│   ├── inventory
│   ├── library
│   └── roles
├── dc
│   ├── group_vars
│   ├── host_vars
│   ├── inventory
│   ├── library
│   └── roles
├── default
│   └── roles
├── site
│   ├── group_vars
│   ├── host_vars
│   ├── inventory
│   ├── library
│   └── roles
└── var
    ├── cache
    ├── log
    ├── retry
    └── templates
```